# upload attachment to SharePoint List Item using REST API from Java client

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload, rest, https

Following Java code is an example for uploading a file attachment to the SharePoint 2013 list item.

```
    String uploadquery =siteurl+ _api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='File1.txt')";

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uploadquery);
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    httppost.addHeader("X-RequestDigest", FormDigestValue);
    httppost.addHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "PUT");
    httppost.addHeader("If-Match", "*");

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("This is a Body");
    httppost.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost, localContext);
```

It creates the file with the content.But it returns the following error in the response.

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The type SP.File does not support HTTP PATCH method."}}}
```

what causes this issue?

in Above code,I upload simple text content.But How to upload other file types such as excel/ppt or images to sharepoint list item ?

Comment: Compare your code with JShare working examples. You can sniff HTTP traffic to find what you are missing http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [Working with folders and files with REST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553(v=office.15).aspx#FileAttachments) the following properties have to be specified for creating file attachment to a list item:

- `POST` method for HTTP request
- `X-RequestDigest` header with `FormDigest` value
- HTTP request `body` and `content length`

Pseudo example:

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items(item id)/AttachmentFiles/ add(FileName='file name')
method: POST
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    body: "Contents of file."
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body
```

### C# example

The following C# code sample demonstrates how to upload create file attachment to a list item using [Network API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net(v=vs.110).aspx) into SharePoint Online (SPO):

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath);
var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('{1}')/items({2})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='{3}')", webUrl, listTitle, itemId,fileName);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Credentials = credentials;  //SharePointOnlineCredentials object 
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");

request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", requestDigest);

var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath);
request.ContentLength = fileContent.Length;
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I believe with minimal effort it could be converted into Java version.