# Create .xlsx file using Sharepoint Rest Api

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, file

Is their any specific headers need to set while creating `.xlsx` file in SharePoint?

I have used the below Rest API code in postman to create the one but getting the attached error while opening the created one in SharePoint.

```
url: http://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/FolderName')/Files/add(url='a.xlsx',overwrite=true)
method: POST
body: "Contents of file in raw plain text"
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    content-length:length of post body
```

[image]

To me it looks like the issue is with the format/content type  of the file which i tried to set via header Content-Type : "application/vnd.ms-excel" but still no luck. Please note i am trying this from Postman

Below is the header section screenshot from Postman

[image]

Comment: you cannot just make an Excel document out of raw plain text. Try this: take your plain text and put it into a text file, then change its extension to xlsx and try to open it. Does it work? That's what you're basically doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call listed below works in case of file extension is xls. It doesn't work in case of xlsx.
I think there should be special syntax to create valid .xlsx file.

Probably this question isn't about headers but about creating valid .xlsx file.

```
var fileContent = 'aaa';

jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/testLib')/Files/add(url='a.xls',overwrite=true)",
        method: "POST",
        cache: true,
        data: fileContent,
        headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": fileContent.length
            },
        success: alert("Yeah"),
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried both xls and xlsx, the file is getting created successfully in the documents folder as expected, the issue (error as attached) comes while opening the file

Comment: @ArpitBhardwaj I tried call above. I can open xls file that was uploaded by this rest call.

Comment: i think you are right, the issue is about the valid xls content. Will check it in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code to create a file in SharePoint library:

```
var restUrl = "http://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/siteName/DocumentLibrary/FolderName')/Files/add(url='a.xlsx', overwrite=true)";

jQuery.ajax({
    url: restUrl,
    type: "POST",
    headers: {        
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(); 
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**Note**: You need to pass the complete server relative URL of folder inside document library to create a file in specific folder.

Comment: It is unable to open the file after uploading by this ajax call.

Comment: the file is getting created successfully in the documents folder as expected, the issue (error as attached) is coming in opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the POST man tool select the binary option where it will allow to attach or browse any file - there you attach any excel file by browsing your local directory - then perform the POST operation to SharePoint, this will upload the document to the SharePoint library - then go to the code section of the POST man tool where we can all equivalent code for this POST operation in almost all coding language like C#, JSON, REST API etc. Then look at the C# coding structure how it got generated automatically and we can use this format of code wherever we want.

**Binary option selection example:**

[image: Binary option selection example]

**How to get the code snippet from POST man tool:**

[image: How to get the code snippet from POST man tool]

**Example:**

Using the below C# REST API code we can add file to SharePoint:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath);
var requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('{1}')/items({2})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='{3}')", webUrl, listTitle, itemId,fileName);
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
request.Credentials = credentials;  //SharePointOnlineCredentials object 
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");

request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", requestDigest);

var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath);
request.ContentLength = fileContent.Length;
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Reference URL:

[upload attachment to SharePoint List Item using REST API from Java client](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111674/upload-attachment-to-sharepoint-list-item-using-rest-api-from-java-client)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/40b0cb04-1fbb-4639-96f3-a95fe3bdbd78/upload-files-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment